# Alert when stored procedure fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to have `SQL Server (2008)` send an email alert if a `stored procedure` fails for *any* reason?

I can do it quite easily from a SQL job but can't see any options within the `Programmability` area or the properties of the `stored procedure` itself. This `stored procedure` is triggered via another application on demand. I have looked at doing it from the other application but this adds many layers of complication-I was hoping `SQL Server` had me covered on this!?

I have searched but not found anyone with the same question.

Thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High level overview of how you can do this..

1.Modify stored Procs to Return 1 in case of failure and log into table.This also has some weakness because [some failures wont be Caught](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)
2.Once the information is logged into table,then sending email is easy using [SP_SEND_DBMAIL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx).

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'Adventure Works Administrator',  
    @recipients = 'yourfriend@Adventure-Works.com',  
    @query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.WorkOrder  
                  WHERE DueDate > ''2004-04-30''  
                  AND  DATEDIFF(dd, ''2004-04-30'', DueDate) < 2' ,  
    @subject = 'stored procedures Failures'
```

If i want to send email,i will use above approach instead of sending email for every failure.Since i logged data into a table,i can run a SQL job every 1 hour or so depending on frequency i  need

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's pretty simple, just use normal error handling such as TRY/CATCH and then in your catch block use sp_send_dbmail to send an email to whatever recipients you require.

Comment: Great, I'll take a look at that function. Thanks! :)

Comment: I'd suggest not to send mail directly from catch - write to your own journal of failed sps and proceed it with job serially. Several errors in one email.

Comment: I guess it depends on the situation, if it's something that is only executed once per day to do some processing, putting it in the try/catch would probably be fine, if it's being executed 5000 times a day, then I guess logging to a table and sending a single email would make sense.